# How To Update A Lot Of Resources?

Tags: c#, winapi, resources

I want to add **many** resources to an exe. I noticed that I can do it this way only for a few resources:

```
// BeginUpdate();
// for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
//     UpdateResource();
// EndUpdate();
```

Because there seems to be a bug or something in WinApi. I'm trying to do it this way now:

```
// for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
// {
//     BeginUpdate();
//     UpdateResource();
//     EndUpdate();
// }
```

But **of course** it doesn't happen. `GetLastError()` returns **sometimes** error codes 5 (*Access is denied*) and 110 (*The system cannot open the device or file specified.*). It works for some resources then error 110 comes in groups. And sometimes error 5 comes up alone. How can I work around those errors ? I must add 1000+ resources and the function must either succeed completely or fail, nothing in between.

---

This is my function that just adds random strings:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetLastError();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename, bool deleteExistingResources);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr resource, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string type, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name, ushort language, IntPtr data, uint dataSize);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr resource, bool discardChanges);

private static void addResources(string filename, int count)
{
    // 1. delete existing resources
    IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource(filename, true);
    Console.WriteLine(EndUpdateResource(handle, false));

    // 2. add resources
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        handle = BeginUpdateResource(filename, false);
        string text = Utils.randomString(16);
        if (!UpdateResource(handle, "TEST", "" + i, 0, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(text), (uint) text.Length))
            Console.WriteLine("update error: " + GetLastError() + ", " + i);
        if (!EndUpdateResource(handle, false))
            Console.WriteLine("endupdate error: " + GetLastError() + ", " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a standard issue with messing with EXE or DLL files.  Virus scanners get *really* exited when they see an executable change out of the blue.  They'll open the file to check it, preventing you from acquiring a lock on it.  You'll have to cool your heels and wait until it is done.  This is not the first hint you have seen that messing with executables is a bad idea iirc.

Comment: I figured that and disabled AV but still had the same problem. I feel like EndUpdate returns quick but is still closing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is only 1 way around this error: **RETRYING**

`EndUpdateResource(...)` tends to fail for no reason *(view of the programmer)*. Reason might be AnitVir or Windows checking the file. It can fail a few or lots of times in a row. Happens especially when you modify resources more than once.

**Solution:** Retry everything from `BeginUpdateResource(...)` to `EndUpdateResource(...)`

```
if (EndUpdateResource(...))
    // success
else
    // retry
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You are calling `BeginUpdateResource()` and `EndUpdateResource()` in the loop. It should only be:

```
handle = BeginUpdateResource(...);
for(...) {
   UpdateResource(...);
}
EndUpdateResource(...);
```

The changes accumulated with `UpdateResource()` are then written together (that's the work of `EndUpdateResource()`), so it provides you the "all or nothing" semantics.

For more info, read the Remarks section of `UpdateResource()` docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It is not, if you want the transactional behavior (do all, or nothing on an error). Then you must call `EndUpdateResource()` once. Or, make the changes on a copy of the .exe and then copy it back to replace the ortiginal if all your changes succeeded.

Comment: Yes, it is! EndUpdateResource fails every time when there are too many resources. It's some kind of defect in WinApi. You probably think theoretically. I have a running code that proves my statement!